How to generate a 50-100 Hz 12 Vac sine wave for audio tone from 5 VDC (PB0 pin) atmega164p microcontroller
I have programmed to ATmega 164P to make PBO high when PC1 is low. In programming, I'm adding other peripherals as well.
But I am facing one issue regarding generating a tone. I have drawn low pass filter and using LM386. But I can't produce 50-100 Hz frequency with 12V ac from 5Vdc pin. I use some circuit but didn't help.
So if you could suggest me about how can I build circuit which can convert 5 VDC to 50-100 Hz 12VAC for generating tone. If you have any suggestion or suggested circuit for me, please let me know. By the way I'm learning timer and counter but couldn't able to program efficient way yet.


(Beware efficient transducers electrical sine-wave to LF audible are large.)

can't produce [12 Vac from 5 Vdc] Well, that isn't easy without a transformer: 12 V "effective" sine means about 34 Vpp (peak-to-peak). Please add to the post how can't produce… shows, motivate "the 12 V requirement" and tell what options you see for power supply - e.g., a 19 V laptop supply.

The issue is about low pass filter which does not produce proper sinewave with high frequency . And im facing this issue badly

Do not comment comments asking for clarification or complementary information: edit your post. I can't see inside your head. No more do I see of your simulation (?) results, your circuit assembly, your measurements than what you present in your posts. You neither tell nor show what signal you generate at PB0. The raster image for the circuit schematic is just small enough to let me doubt what component values I see -  27 μH, 100 μF? Shouldn't that yield a "cut-off" frequency in the 100 kHz ballpark?

(Without a well-known signal source&load, high order passive filter design/construction doesn't look promising. I'd advise to look at active filters if I thought your point was "analogue" signal processing - is it? If what you want is to actually hear something, shift frequency up 3 octaves or a full decade.)

There are many issues in the circuit, but use 3 R/C low pass combinations of 47 kohm and 100 nF and a decoupling capacitor in front of RV1 for a start. An arduino port cannot drive a 10 ohm load. With LM386 you will not reach 12 VAC at a typical speaker, look for BTL type amplifiers.
